# MikTeX 2.8 doesn't add hyphenation support for pdfLaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex, miktex, hyphenation, babeljs

I'm using MikTeX 2.8 edition, and installed the hungarian language support and hyphenation files. Using the standard LaTeX command they work fine, but when I try to use pdfLaTeX, they don't get loaded and I get the

```
(C:\stuff\miktex\tex\generic\babel\magyar.ldf
(C:\stuff\miktex\tex\generic\babel\babel.def)
Package babel /b/c12/cWarning:/b/c0/c No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel)                the language `Magyar'
(babel)                I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.
```

message. Using latex it works fine:

```
(C:\stuff\miktex\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg)
(C:\stuff\miktex\tex\generic\babel\magyar.ldf
(C:\stuff\miktex\tex\generic\babel\babel.def)))
```

I tried updating the FNDB and the Formats, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing MikTeX 2.8 and cleaning the registry by hand, then reinstalling it solved the problem. (simply removing and reinstalling didn't solve it)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in Windows 7. I installed MikTeX and configured the hyphenation languages under administrator account and when I started to use pdflatex under my own account, it turned out that it did not detect the languages that I had added in the MikTex Settings (Admin) application.

The solution was to run MikTex Settings under my own account (i.e. the non-Admin program in Start Menu) and click the button "Update Formats".

Comment: This answer helped me a lot... tried to figure out my problem for like 2 hours now and it turned out that my problem was exactly what you mentioned in the last sentence!

update formats in user-mode and now my tex configuration knows about the hyphenation finally, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with MiKTeX 2.8, babel, pdflatex and language "portuguese". 
Regular latex works fine.

Went back to MiKTeX 2.7 and the problem doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

First find out language.dat file under your installation. Then find there a string like %magyar bla-bla-bla, remove comment (% mark), or, if there is no such line in that file - add it. Bla-bla-bla stands for the exact name of file with hyphenation table, you should google of how does that called.

Then run "update formats" from the miktex options menu, BUT - do that for the Options, and NOT for Options (Admin) menu.

Good luck!